# Demo projects not building

Tags: codenameone

Hi Ive been able to build my own hello project but ALL the demo projects fail with odd build error they cant find source which is in the Hello project see pics. Must be settings in Netbeans Project but I cant find appreciate any advice. Error /home/alistair/netbeansprojects/codenameone/CameraDemo/build.xml:51: taskdef class com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBkeb.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpYIM.png

Comment: Just a supposition : have you included the codename one sources on the demoApplication ? Maybe if you defined a new codename one project and then you import demo application it'll works

Comment: I guess you got these from github. You shouldn't unless you know what you are doing as those require some configuration. There is a simpler way. Use File -> New Project -> Codename One/Demos and pick your demo of choice.

Comment: @Shai I just ran into the same error when transferring a project from netbeans to intellij.  I opened a new cn1 project in intellij and made symlinks to `src/`, `res/` and all the other relevant files.  This strategy has worked for me in the past, but now it's not.  Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: We make a lot of assumptions about project structures so we can hide a lot of the complexity. You can't symlink or try to workaround these assumptions

Comment: @Shai Btw symlinking works fine if you catch all the right files; this error is unrelated (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when moving a project to a new computer.  On the new machine, I had installed JDK 9, whereas on the old machine I had been working with Java 1.8.  I downloaded Java 1.8 and selected it as the project SDK, and the error went away.